# TypeError: Object of type WorkItem is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I received this error after running the script below. I would like to create a json file through the result that is generated in this script. What can I do to correct this problem?

I tried to do it via API but I couldn't get the fields I need from this DevOps table.

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v5_1.work_item_tracking.models import Wiql
import json

token = 'xxx'
team_instance = 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx'

credentials = BasicAuthentication("", token)
connection = Connection(base_url=team_instance, creds=credentials)

def print_work_items(work_items):
    for work_item in work_items:
        with open('teste_project.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(work_items, json_file)

wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

def get_TC_from_query(query):
    query_wiql = Wiql(query=query)
    results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(query_wiql).work_items
    # WIQL query gives a WorkItemReference => we get the corresponding WorkItem from id
    work_items = (wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results)
    print_work_items(work_items)

get_TC_from_query(
    """\
SELECT *
FROM workitems
WHERE
        [System.TeamProject] = 'xxx'
        and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item'
        and [System.State] = 'Done'
ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
"""
)
```

> TypeError: Object of type WorkItem is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) provided by @jordanm. You can override the default() method to serialize additional types.

I made below changes to your code, and it worked when i tested.

> First make work_items a list:

`work_items = [wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results]`

> Then in `print_work_items` method, i override the `default` method in `json.dump()` with `default = lambda o: o.__dict__`. Please check below:

```
def print_work_items(work_items):
    for work_item in work_items:
        with open('teste_project.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(work_items, json_file, default = lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: I am not able to read this json generated in a databricks table. I tried to apply StringIO but I was unsuccessful, what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The following produces a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which JSON can not serialize:

```
work_items = (wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results)
```

You can instead make `work_items` a list, which JSON can serialize:

```
work_items = [wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results]
```

Comment: I continue with error:"TypeError: Object of type WorkItem is not JSON serializable". 
I will update the script

Comment: @FelipeFB either see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3768895/1032785) or abstract the data you want out of the `WorkItem` objects. JSON only supports a handful of basic types.